# how can i train two tensorflow scripts on single gpu parallelly?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, gpu, multiple-instances

I am getting error when i run 2 tensorflow scripts on single GPU.
I have tried growth and GPU memory allocations steps, still the first script executes without problem while 2nd script failes with ResourceExhaustedError , Graph session creation error.

Kindly help.

Comment: what do you see when you run nvidia-smi during this?

Answer (score 1):

Run each program separately first for a few iterations and check `nvidia-smi dmon` to see how much memory that program actually requires. Then set `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = ...` in your session configuration based on the memory information you learned from `nvidia-smi dmon`. If the memory required for both is greater than what you have available then you will run into this resources exhausted error.

Comment: Hi, I am using script
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4

print('Checking the Training on a Single Batch...')
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
 in both the scripts
===============================
# gpu   pwr  temp    sm   mem   enc   dec  mclk  pclk
# Idx     W     C     %     %     %     %   MHz   MHz
    0   138    46    74    43     0     0  2505   875
..
    0   139    47    84    48     0     0  2505   875
    0   132    47   100    51     0     0  2505   771

Comment: i.e - Memory goes from 47-53% though i am limiting the gpu_memory_fraction @ 0.4. I guess thats why the second script(which is exactly same but run by different user) is failing.

Comment: Please can you advice?

Comment: Also i limited per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3 in both scripts, still second script fails.

Comment: If you're model is taking up 47%-53% of GPU you need to allocate at least that much. If that still doesn't work you may be running out of memory during your initial data load depending on how your doing it. If you're using a tensorflor CSV or raw file data loader you should be fine. If you're reading into a different format using something like numpy and then using a `feed_dict` that may take up more memory in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I will test with lower batch size and add my comments

Comment: Hi, I reduced my batch size to 16, GPy memory stat was less than 49%, when i ran second script it again failed with same error. As you mentioned, i believe passing CIFAR-10 set using numpy would be the problem. 

now, i am testing on MNIST set, I will update my observation

Comment: 2 people can work on MNIST - works without problem. GPU usage is less than 25%. Hence i can conclude from observation that parallel operation in GPU is possible with small dataset, but cannot happen on large datasets like CIFAR-10

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
# don't allow cases where a single script takes up all VRAM
# this way we can try to run several scripts at the same time
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    ...
```

If any of you know how to train two graphs in parallel in a single script, please let me know.